# Passing cpu core to multiworkermirrored strategy()

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to implement mirrored strategy using cpu's but i dont know how to frame the parameters to be passed to `mirroredstrategy()`. This is the line of code as it is for gpu's, `distribution = tf.contrib.distribute.MultiworkerMirroredStrategy(["/device:GPU:0", "/device:GPU:1", "/device:GPU:2"])`

i could change "/device:GPU:0", to "/device:CPU:0", but that seems to only use one core or does it , how would i check?

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow can make use of multiple CPU cores out of the box, so you do not need to use a strategy in this case. `MultiworkerMirroredStrategy` is only needed if you want to train with multiple machines. Those machines can each have GPU(s) or be CPU only.